# MySQL tmp_table_size for a small database

Tags: mysql, mysqltuner

I have MySQL 5.7.23 on Ubuntu 18.04. It's a VPS with 2 vCores and 8 GiB of RAM. The server is hosting two WordPress websites. Each website has a database with the size of 7,5 MB. So there is 15 MB database overall.

I was trying to optimize the database using [mysqltuner](https://github.com/major/MySQLTuner-perl). It recommends me everytime the same thing:

```
Variables to adjust:
    tmp_table_size (> 64M)
    max_heap_table_size (> 64M)
```

I started with 16M, then I was recommended to increase the value to 32M and now it recommends me to increase the value to 64M or more. But why? Total size of all my databases is ~15M.

I have enough memory, free memory is around 6,5 GiB so I can use much more memory for MySQL.

The complete log from mysqltuner is

```
root@web:~# perl mysqltuner.pl
 >>  MySQLTuner 1.7.10 - Major Hayden <major@mhtx.net>
 >>  Bug reports, feature requests, and downloads at http://mysqltuner.com/
 >>  Run with '--help' for additional options and output filtering

[--] Skipped version check for MySQLTuner script
[OK] Logged in using credentials from Debian maintenance account.
[OK] Currently running supported MySQL version 5.7.23-0ubuntu0.18.04.1
[OK] Operating on 64-bit architecture

-------- Log file Recommendations ----------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                             --------------------
[--] Log file: /var/log/mysql/error.log(0B)
[OK] Log file /var/log/mysql/error.log exists
[OK] Log file /var/log/mysql/error.log is readable.
[!!] Log file /var/log/mysql/error.log is empty
[OK] Log file /var/log/mysql/error.log is smaller than 32 Mb
[OK] /var/log/mysql/error.log doesn't contain any warning.
[OK] /var/log/mysql/error.log doesn't contain any error.
[--] 0 start(s) detected in /var/log/mysql/error.log
[--] 0 shutdown(s) detected in /var/log/mysql/error.log

-------- Storage Engine Statistics ---------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                             --------------------
[--] Status: +ARCHIVE +BLACKHOLE +CSV -FEDERATED +InnoDB +MEMORY +MRG_MYISAM +My                                                                                                                                                             ISAM +PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA
[--] Data in InnoDB tables: 14.2M (Tables: 45)
[OK] Total fragmented tables: 0

-------- Security Recommendations ----------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                             --------------------
[OK] There are no anonymous accounts for any database users
[OK] All database users have passwords assigned
[--] Bug #80860 MySQL 5.7: Avoid testing password when validate_password is acti                                                                                                                                                             vated

-------- CVE Security Recommendations ------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                             --------------------
[--] Skipped due to --cvefile option undefined

-------- Performance Metrics ---------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                             --------------------
[--] Up for: 1d 2h 43m 42s (84K q [0.879 qps], 1K conn, TX: 441M, RX: 12M)
[--] Reads / Writes: 98% / 2%
[--] Binary logging is disabled
[--] Physical Memory     : 7.8G
[--] Max MySQL memory    : 384.4M
[--] Other process memory: 252.8M
[--] Total buffers: 224.0M global + 1.1M per thread (151 max threads)
[--] P_S Max memory usage: 72B
[--] Galera GCache Max memory usage: 0B
[OK] Maximum reached memory usage: 228.3M (2.86% of installed RAM)
[OK] Maximum possible memory usage: 384.4M (4.82% of installed RAM)
[OK] Overall possible memory usage with other process is compatible with memory                                                                                                                                                              available
[OK] Slow queries: 0% (0/84K)
[OK] Highest usage of available connections: 2% (4/151)
[OK] Aborted connections: 0.00%  (0/1561)
[OK] Query cache is disabled by default due to mutex contention on multiprocesso                                                                                                                                                             r machines.
[OK] Sorts requiring temporary tables: 0% (0 temp sorts / 12K sorts)
[OK] No joins without indexes
[!!] Temporary tables created on disk: 44% (3K on disk / 7K total)
[OK] Thread cache hit rate: 99% (4 created / 1K connections)
[OK] Table cache hit rate: 77% (1K open / 1K opened)
[OK] Open file limit used: 1% (56/5K)
[OK] Table locks acquired immediately: 100% (202 immediate / 202 locks)

-------- Performance schema ----------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                             --------------------
[--] Memory used by P_S: 72B
[--] Sys schema is installed.

-------- ThreadPool Metrics ----------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                             --------------------
[--] ThreadPool stat is disabled.

-------- MyISAM Metrics --------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                             --------------------
[!!] Key buffer used: 18.3% (3M used / 16M cache)
[OK] Key buffer size / total MyISAM indexes: 16.0M/43.0K
[OK] Read Key buffer hit rate: 96.3% (190 cached / 7 reads)

-------- InnoDB Metrics --------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                             --------------------
[--] InnoDB is enabled.
[--] InnoDB Thread Concurrency: 0
[OK] InnoDB File per table is activated
[OK] InnoDB buffer pool / data size: 128.0M/14.2M
[OK] Ratio InnoDB log file size / InnoDB Buffer pool size: 16.0M * 2/128.0M shou                                                                                                                                                             ld be equal 25%
[OK] InnoDB buffer pool instances: 1
[--] Number of InnoDB Buffer Pool Chunk : 1 for 1 Buffer Pool Instance(s)
[OK] Innodb_buffer_pool_size aligned with Innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size & Innodb                                                                                                                                                             _buffer_pool_instances
[OK] InnoDB Read buffer efficiency: 99.96% (2124360 hits/ 2125302 total)
[!!] InnoDB Write Log efficiency: 83.91% (9286 hits/ 11067 total)
[OK] InnoDB log waits: 0.00% (0 waits / 1781 writes)

-------- AriaDB Metrics --------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                             --------------------
[--] AriaDB is disabled.

-------- TokuDB Metrics --------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                             --------------------
[--] TokuDB is disabled.

-------- XtraDB Metrics --------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                             --------------------
[--] XtraDB is disabled.

-------- RocksDB Metrics -------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                             --------------------
[--] RocksDB is disabled.

-------- Spider Metrics --------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                             --------------------
[--] Spider is disabled.

-------- Connect Metrics -------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                             --------------------
[--] Connect is disabled.

-------- Galera Metrics --------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                             --------------------
[--] Galera is disabled.

-------- Replication Metrics ---------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                             --------------------
[--] Galera Synchronous replication: NO
[--] No replication slave(s) for this server.
[--] Binlog format: ROW
[--] XA support enabled: ON
[--] Semi synchronous replication Master: Not Activated
[--] Semi synchronous replication Slave: Not Activated
[--] This is a standalone server

-------- Recommendations -------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                             --------------------
General recommendations:
    When making adjustments, make tmp_table_size/max_heap_table_size equal
    Reduce your SELECT DISTINCT queries which have no LIMIT clause
Variables to adjust:
    tmp_table_size (> 64M)
    max_heap_table_size (> 64M)
```

Comment: What's the difference between 16MB and 64MB on a modern system where you're going to get >10GB of disk space? These defaults were from an era where a 2GB drive was considered impossibly huge and 1GB of memory was still a hypothetical. I'd follow the advice of the tuning tool unless you had a very specific reason not to.

Comment: Thank you. I did not know if cannot even slow down the database. I don't know the background of database systems, so I don't know how this can impact the server overall. It can possibly even slow down the server if it would require saving more data to disk instead of to RAM.

Comment: You're talking about 48MB of memory, an amount that's pretty much irrelevant on a machine of that spec. That's not going to have a measurable impact. If you were talking about bumping from 16MB to 4GB I'd understand your concern, that's 50% of system memory vs. 48MB being 0.6%.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should take Mysqltuner recommendations with a grain of salt. Its suggestions are not made with any knowledge of your database or your queries, and sometimes they are just guesses based on incomplete information.

Edit: Having seen more cases of erroneous advice given by Mysqltuner, I caution more strongly against using it. Just delete Mysqltuner from your computer and forget it ever existed.

The suggestion to increase the tmp_table_size might be based on reading the status values that indicate some temp tables were created on disk.

```
mysql> show global status like 'created%tables';
+-------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name           | Value |
+-------------------------+-------+
| Created_tmp_disk_tables | 35    |
| Created_tmp_tables      | 274   |
+-------------------------+-------+
```

"Aha!" says mysqltuner, "13% of your temp tables were on disk. Those might have stayed in RAM if we allowed larger temp tables to stay in RAM. Double the tmp_table_size!"

But some temp tables are *always* created on disk.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/internal-temporary-tables.html says:

> Some query conditions prevent the use of an in-memory temporary table,
> in which case the server uses an on-disk table instead:
>
> - Presence of a BLOB or TEXT column in the table. This includes
>   user-defined variables having a string value because they are treated
>   as BLOB or TEXT columns, depending on whether their value is a binary
>   or nonbinary string, respectively.
> - Presence of any string column with a maximum length larger than 512
>   (bytes for binary strings, characters for nonbinary strings) in the
>   SELECT list, if UNION or UNION ALL is used.
> - The SHOW COLUMNS and DESCRIBE statements use BLOB as the type for some
>   columns, thus the temporary table used for the results is an on-disk
>   table.

How could mysqltuner tell the difference between temp tables that went to disk because they were too large, versus temp tables that went to disk because of one of the conditions above?

It can't tell the difference. It would have to read your query log and analyze each query, but it doesn't do this. It only knows the count of how many temp tables were on disk, not *why*.

Mysqltuner only assumes that a temp table was stored on disk because it was larger than tmp_table_size, and it assumes that there will be some benefit to increasing tmp_table_size.

Comment: Thank you Bill for the explanation. So it's "secure" to increase the values even higher with no negative impact, correct? So even for example 512M is fine for my config (mainly capacity of RAM probably).

Comment: Probably safe. It won't use that memory unless and until queries that create temp tables are running, and it won't use the whole 512M if the temp table is smaller.

Comment: On the other hand, if it's possible for *many* queries to be running concurrently, all creating temp tables, and all of them use up to 512M of memory, then that can add up to a much larger amount, and probably without warning.

Comment: Thank you again Bill. I will follow recommendations of the tool. Now it looks that 256M is enough, so I will not higher the value and I will monitor it. I am still on the same memory usage level somewhere around 1,2 GB for the whole system.

Answer (score 0):

Rule of Thumb:  These should be under 1% of RAM:

```
tmp_table_size
max_heap_table_size
```

If you make them too big, you risk swapping, which is really bad for performance.

(I'm with Bill on having a negative opinion of some advice from mysqltuner.)